# Using event based architecture to receive notifications from external systems?

Tags: integration, platform-event

We're using an integration layer between SAP and Salesforce and I wonder about the general structure for an event based architecture. How would I go about listening to events coming **from** our integration layer?

I can use change data capture to set up events that are triggered whenever a record in Salesforce is updated/created, but what if we need some finance data from SAP - or any other system for that matter - how can I subscribe to a specific event from our integration layer and get the requested data?

Is Streaming API the solution? That only provides the actual event I guess, but how will the data be sent?

Comment: There are two models for this: polling (where Salesforce interrogates the external system) or push (where the external system invokes a Salesforce (REST) API). Salesforce provides some layered abstractions too, such as External Objects. How you do this depends on several factors, including "data ownership" (which system owns the data), update frequencies and data volumes being three significant ones. You can find plenty of info about this elsewhere, but importantly you need to realise that Salesforce cannot miraculously cause SAP to send data to it - you need to make SAP do the send to an API.

Comment: Or you make Saleforce call SAP to fetch specific data (though I personally would try to avoid this approach in 98% of cases).

Comment: You might like to look at MuleSoft integration middleware too.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear - SAP does send the data to our integration layer - we have a system similar to Mulesoft already in place. My concern is just how that data should be transmitted from our integration layer to Salesforce. If this can be done through some form of event based architecture where we subscribe to one of their events or something. 
Otherwise, I was thinking of setting up platform events that the integration layer simply makes a rest callout to, but do I have any other options? Polling is out of the question, so are external objects. We want it to be as event based as possible

Comment: Why not just call the standard Salesforce REST API? I assume you are just pushing data to Salesforce, right? The "event" is a record creation, update or delete. I see zero gain in trying to use Platform Events in this context. How would that help? The events are emitted from Salesforce or SAP to your Middleware which then transforms the event into a data insert/update/delete API call on the opposite system.

Comment: Perhaps you're right. I just assumed there was some way of having an event based structure all the way where SAP publishes events to the integration layer, and then salesforce is subscribed to the integration layer.